# Altering row data while using Oracle expdp utility

Tags: oracle, remap, expdp

I'm a developer -not a DBA or DB expert - but as part of my job I should be able to export data to get it imported into another DB. While exporting I need to be able to alter row data that is going into dump files. Is that possible? Let's say I have a column `ID` with value `1,2,3,4...` and while exporting I should be able to do `ID * -1` for the result data `-1,-2,-3,-4...`. This would help me in migrating data when there's data already present in the target DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `expdp` [`REMAP_DATA`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL861) option to do this, assuming you can create a package and function to do the conversion:

With some simple data:

```
create table t42 (id number);

insert into t42 select level from dual connect by level <= 5;

select * from t42;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
```

... and a package function:

```
create package p42 as
    function negate(p_number in number) return number;
end p42;
/

create package body p42 as
    function negate(p_number in number) return number is
    begin
        return -1 * p_number;
    end;
end p42;
/
```

You can export with `remap_data`, and then import, in this test back into the same DB/schema:

```
expdp directory=data_pump_dir dumpfile=d42.dmp nologfile=yes tables=t42 \
    remap_data=t42.id:p42.negate
impdp directory=data_pump_dir dumpfile=d42.dmp nologfile=yes tables=t42 \
    content=data_only
```

The table now has:

```
select * from t42;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
        -1
        -2
        -3
        -4
        -5
```

You can do the same modification on import as well, using the `impdp` [`REMAP_DATA`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL925) parameter instead. The principle is the same, just depends at what point you want to modify the data.

Comment: Will definitely serve my purpose. Will dig more on REMAP_DATA to find what more we can do with it. Thanks